# Ironing and Steaming Clothing on Shabbath

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work

Is one allowed to iron or steam their clothing on Shabbath?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Is there a way to do so without using electricity or boiling water?

Comment: @mbloch perhaps if they left the iron on a timer and didn't use water? Mikayah, in every halachic training course worth it's salt, people are trained to clarify exactly what the case is. Could you aid us and state clearly what you mean by ironing or steaming, how it would work (assume we are idiots, we won't mind!) and what you think might be wrong about it?

Answer (score 2):

No not allowed:

Even if you could boil water (ie: Yom Tov), or used a radiator that was on, or had natural heat (ie: sun) this is the Melacha of Melabin. To Clean a garment.

Please see מ׳׳א סי׳ ש׳׳א ס׳׳ק נ׳׳ז also see מ׳׳ב שם ס׳׳ק קס׳׳ט where מ׳׳ב writes:

> אע״ג דאפילו בחמה אסור וכנ״ל התם משום מראית העין לחוד הוא וקמ״ל הכא
> דנגד האש יש איסור תורה משום מבשל ומשום מלבן [דדרך להתלבן ע״י התנור
> כדאמרינן שבת כ״ז האונין של פשתן משיתלבנו] וגם דאסור מחמת זה לנגבן
> אפילו כשהוא לבוש בהם אם הוא עומד נגד החום במקום שהיד סולדת בהם:
>
> Even the sun is prohibited, it appears to me, because it appears that
> he has done something wrong to onlookers, here the [Shulchan Aruch prohibits with
> fire] teaching that the [drying with] fire is a Torah prohibition of cooking and
> cleaning (it is a way to clean via oven like it says in Gemara
> Shabbos) and so it is a prohibition to dry them even when he wears
> them if he stands outside where the heat causes Yad Soledes.

Comment: using a dry (non steam) iron on a dry shirt... no cleaning or drying of the garment occurs (i would think)... but still lots of other considerations..

Comment: I suppose I'd have to know more about a dry iron to see if it makes a difference. Thank you